# Use QUERY to get Avg of last x entries matching conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to refine my coding for a working spreadsheet by updating all the code to `QUERY` functions.  One thing I am stuck on is where I average the last x rows matching specific conditions.

I was hoping that the following formula would work:

```
=QUERY(Ladder!A2:AE,"Select Avg(J) where F = '"&H$1&"' order by B desc limit "&$C$5)
```

My thought being that this would return the average of the last 3 rows - but I receive the

> COL_IN_ORDER_MUST_BE_IN_SELECT error.

I only want the formula to return a single cell with the % average in it.

I realise that I could use the following code and then `QUERY` the Avg of that, but I want to be able to return % values for each different deck.

Here's a link to a cut down version of the spreadsheet:

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bt5wXrBrM7Qrp5XAAiAALbFwmpUxDXqZyuYElhMmb0E/edit?usp=sharing)

Ladder:  Where I enter the data
Ladder Filter:  Where the data will filter based on query commands depending on criteria in the Ladder Stats tab
Ladder Stats:  Where I can view all statistics and generate various statistical reports

It's all working at the moment, but as you can see it's very clunky and formula-heavy.  I've worked most of it out except for the scenario you will find on the "Ladder Stats" tab - whereby B3="" and C5 != NULL.  It is designed to give statistics for the last x games played by each of the decks.

Comment: It's a big hot mess tbh

Comment: Edited original post and added a cut down version of the spreadsheet @player0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use a double query like this and format cell as `%`

```
=QUERY(QUERY(Ladder!A2:AE, 
 "select J 
  where F = '"&H$1&"' 
  order by B desc 
  limit "&$C$5, 0),
 "select avg(Col1)
  label avg(Col1)''", 0)
```

[image]

---

or you can use `AVERAGE` formula and click twice to get decimal position:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(Ladder!A2:AE, 
 "select J 
  where F = '"&H$1&"' 
  order by B desc 
  limit "&$C$5, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you so much :D

Comment: I used your solution all throughout my spreadsheet and it greatly reduced the volume of formulae - but it MASSIVELY increased the processing time LOL

My PC runs VR flawlessly, but there was no way it was processing all those queries!  So I had to drop a heap of them back to COUNTIFS and AVERAGEIFS.  It's still a tonne more efficient than it was, and I'm using your solution in some critical areas of the sheet, so thanks heaps!